Store multiple arrays of 2D dimensional coordinate in one file
I have some arrays of coordinate points, and I want to store them in one file, but I want to delimit them.
What i do :
array1 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
array2 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
np.savetxt('test1.txt', array1)
np.savetxt('test2.txt', array2)

test1.txt example
8.178330983529058518e-01 7.846138841153188492e-01
7.411074030801956258e-01 6.164560724010209602e-01

How can I store them in the same file with a delimiter ? I'm not specifically looking for a .txt file, but rather a file that I can read afterward.
I want something like that :
8.178330983529058518e-01 7.846138841153188492e-01
7.411074030801956258e-01 6.164560724010209602e-01
%%%%%
6.732533221094740838e-01 7.317714192847557531e-02
9.745692442064657346e-01 2.045576523239983624e-01


How are you trying to read it afterward?

@pho if it is a txt file with a classic readline method

You mean you'll read the file line by line and build your arrays based on whether the line you read is a comment or a row of numbers? In that case Tula Ram Sahu's answer is the best way

The answer by Tula Ram Sahu is the best to produce a txt file. Now if you want something that is both (reasonably) human readable and easier to parse, you may consider json.
import json

import numpy as np

array1 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
array2 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
data = {"array1": array1.tolist(), "array2": array2.tolist()}
savefile = "my_save.json"
with open(savefile, "w") as out:
    json.dump(data, out, indent=2, sort_keys=True)

# read with
with open(savefile, "r") as fin:
    data_loaded = json.load(fin)  # native python dict

recovered1 = np.array(data_loaded["array1"])
recovered2 = np.array(data_loaded["array2"])

Finally, if you just want a savefile and binary format is fine, then you should use np.savez or np.savez_compressed.
import numpy as np

array1 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
array2 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
savefile = "my_save.npz"
np.savez_compressed(savefile, array1=array1, array2=array2)

# read with
with np.load(savefile) as fin:
    recovered1 = fin["array1"]
    recovered2 = fin["array2"]


Nice one with the json format, the reading is easylier i will try it too, thanks you

import numpy as np
with open('test1.txt', 'a') as file:
for k in range(1, 30):

    array1 = np.random.rand(2, 2)
    np.savetxt(file, array1, delimiter=' ', newline='\n', fmt='%1.18e', header='', footer='', comments='')
    file.write('%%%%%\n')


Thanks, I was considering this approach, but I thought there might be a more native solution with NumPy. Now, I'll go with this method.
